# Is 14.04 still offtopic?

Tags: discussion

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 and I thought that I can't ask questions about it till it's officially released later this month, but I see many users asking about 14.04. So is it still off topic (Ubuntu +1) or can we start asking about it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj sorry but I had to ask

Comment: It's ok. Sometimes you need an update. Duping this just shows nothing changed ;)

Comment: You can ask on http://superuser.com/ if you don't question to closed because the Ubuntu distribution is not officially supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

Bugs are off-topic as always however. Since all the feature freezes have happened we're getting a little more tolerant ;)

Comment: I had to ask cause of this mainly http://askubuntu.com/questions/441415/what-has-jockey-been-replaced-with-in-14-04

Comment: @Fischer Yes, I understand. Oli is a moderator though ;)

Comment: ones like that are not "AHHH, a bug broke my 14.04 - fix it!" so asking about a feature after feature freeze is very answerable.